# hasMany Laravel Not working

Tags: php, laravel

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->with(['experiences_user'])->first();
        dd($user->experiences_user());
```

When i execute dd it's not showing the values of relationship have.

```
relations: array:1 [▼
    "experiences_user" => Collection {#196 ▼
      #items: []
    }
```

User Model Relationships:

```
 public function experiences_user(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\experiences', 'User_id');
    }
```

Experiences Model Relationships:

```
public function employee(){
    return  $this->belongsTo('App\User','User_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: you need to show other data as well .. specifically the Model .. migration table

Comment: @HamzaMohamed i have updated the relationship

Comment: please share the migartion table as well ..
can you use it like this .. `$user = User::where('id', $id)->first();` then `dd($user->experiences_user());`?

Comment: @HamzaMohamed HasMany {#195 ▼
  #foreignKey: "experience.user_id"
  #localKey: "id"

Comment: okay so you have a fireignKey specified .. can you share the other Model relation and your migration for both?

Comment: @HamzaMohamed i have updated the quesiton with relationship

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166922/discussion-between-paulo-rodrigues-and-hamza-mohamed).

Comment: that experience_user relation didnt has user_id before!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try lazy loading:

```php
$user = User::where('id', $id)->first()->load('experiences_user');
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `$user` of `id=$id` has `experiences_user` items? Just check in your database.

Comment: Yes User _id have experiences_user